# marker clusters not loading properly - Google maps V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps v3 with marker clustering.
My issue is, Many of the markers are not loading during the initial page load, if i mention the minZoom as '1'. If mention it as '2', all markers are showing properly.
Kindly anyone tell me about this issue.

```
function initialize(){
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var myOptions = { 
        minZoom: 1, 
        disableDefaultUI: false, 
        mapTypeControl: true, 
        zoomControl: true, 
        zoomControlOptions: { 
            style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE, 
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER 
        }, 
        streetViewControl: true, 
        keyboardShortcuts: false, 
        center: myLatlng, 
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN 
    };
```

[NOTE: While i mention the minZoom as '1', only few markers are visible initially. If i make any interaction with map[ie., dragging the map] the markers gets appears.]

Comment: Can you show us the remainder of your code, i.e. the rest of myOptions, and then what you do with it.

Comment: `var myOptions = {
minZoom: 1,
disableDefaultUI: false,
mapTypeControl: true,
zoomControl: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
},
streetViewControl: true,
keyboardShortcuts: false,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};`

Comment: What are you using for clustering (there are several different libraries that do this)

Comment: I m using the concept of 'MarkerClusterer for Google Maps v3'

Comment: then just use the proper minZoom. Maybe there are some issues with coordinates when repeating the globe  ...